# Highcharts - How to force dataLabels to show labels when overlapping the content

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, overlap

I need to show all the data (even if one overlaps the other), but automatically one disappears when the boxes are very close:

http://jsfiddle.net/vdgphk3L/

[image]

The [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) recommend `allowOverlap`, but when I use appear two values Min and Max, but I need only Min:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            allowOverlap: true
        }
    }
}
```

Complete code:

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange',
      inverted: false,
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 'Title 5'],
      alternateGridColor: '#F6F9FC',
    },

    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      width: 20,
      formatter: function() {
        var retorno = '<strong>Prices</strong>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
          if (point.series.name == 'Min' || point.series.name == 'Med' || point.series.name == 'Max') {
            retorno += '<br /><span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
          }
        });

        return retorno;
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        grouping: false,
        pointWidth: 70
      },
      series: {
        lineWidth: 0.5
      }
    },

    series: [

      // Min
      {
        name: 'Min',
        color: '#C30000',
        minPointLength: 25,
        data: [
          [2000, 2001],
          [5000, 5001],
          [1000, 1001],
          [8000, 8001],
          [3500, 3501]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          inside: true,
          enabled: true,
          align: 'right',
          format: '{point.y}',
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Min (Line)',
        color: '#C30000',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [2000],
          [5000],
          [1000],
          [8000],
          [3500]
        ]
      },

      // Med
      {
        name: 'Med',
        color: '#215994',
        minPointLength: 25,
        data: [
          [3000, 3001],
          [6001, 6002],
          [3001, 3002],
          [9001, 9002],
          [4001, 4160]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: true,
          align: 'center',
          format: '{point.y}'

        }
      }, {
        name: 'Med (Line)',
        color: '#215994',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [3000],
          [6001],
          [3001],
          [9001],
          [4001]
        ]
      },

      // Max
      {
        name: 'Max',
        color: '#ECEC09',
        minPointLength: 25,
        data: [
          [4000, 4001],
          [7001, 7002],
          [5001, 5002],
          [9501, 9502],
          [4501, 4502]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: true,
          align: 'left',
          format: '{point.y}'
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Max (Line)',
        color: '#ECEC09',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [4000],
          [7001],
          [5001],
          [9501],
          [4501]
        ]
      }

    ]

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing the `dataLabel` format you added and adding a new one I was able to achieve what you are after with use of allowOverlap.

```
plotOptions: {
  columnrange: {
    dataLabels: {
      allowOverlap: true,
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.y == this.point.low) { 
        //this is needed because highcharts draws 2 boxes for columnrange
        //1 for high series and 1 for low series
          return this.point.low;
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

In the fiddle I also moved the consistent plot options out of each series and into `plotOptions`.

```js
function numberToReal(numero) {
  var numero = numero.toFixed(2).split('.');
  numero[0] = "R$ " + numero[0].split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/).join('.');
  return numero.join(',');
}

$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
      type: 'columnrange',
      inverted: false,
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', 'Title 4', 'Title 5'],
      alternateGridColor: '#F6F9FC',
    },

    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      width: 20,
      formatter: function() {
        var retorno = '<strong>Prices</strong>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
          if (point.series.name == 'Min' || point.series.name == 'Med' || point.series.name == 'Max') {
            retorno += '<br /><span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> ' + point.series.name + ': ' + numberToReal(point.y);
          }
        });

        return retorno;
      }
    },

    plotOptions: {
      columnrange: {
        grouping: false,
        pointWidth: 70,
        minPointLength: 25,
        dataLabels: {
          inside: true,
          enabled: true,
          allowOverlap: true,
          formatter: function() {
            if (this.y == this.point.low) {
           return this.point.low;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: {
        lineWidth: 0.5
      }
    },

    series: [

      // Min
      {
        name: 'Min',
        color: '#C30000',
        data: [
          [2000, 2001],
          [5000, 5001],
          [1000, 1001],
          [8000, 8001],
          [3500, 3501]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'right',
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Min (Line)',
        color: '#C30000',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [2000],
          [5000],
          [1000],
          [8000],
          [3500]
        ]
      },

      // Med
      {
        name: 'Med',
        color: '#215994',
        data: [
          [3000, 3001],
          [6001, 6002],
          [3001, 3002],
          [9001, 9002],
          [4001, 4160]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'center',
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Med (Line)',
        color: '#215994',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [3000],
          [6001],
          [3001],
          [9001],
          [4001]
        ]
      },

      // Max
      {
        name: 'Max',
        color: '#ECEC09',
        data: [
          [4000, 4001],
          [7001, 7002],
          [5001, 5002],
          [9501, 9502],
          [4501, 4502]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'left',
        }
      }, {
        name: 'Max (Line)',
        color: '#ECEC09',
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        data: [
          [4000],
          [7001],
          [5001],
          [9501],
          [4501]
        ]
      }

    ]

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Edit:** Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420143/highcharts-custom-datalabels-duplicating) I understood why it is drawing 2 labels. I have updated this post so that it will only draw 1 label now.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vdgphk3L/80/

Comment: Nice, but now each box have 2 values with same value, I need only one value on each box, now have this (Yellow: 4000,4000... Blue: 3000,3000... Red: 2000,2000), I need only (Yellow: 4000, Blue: 3000, Red: 2000)

Comment: What do you mean 2 values with the same value? Look at the example I posted, could you point out what is wrong with a picture?

Comment: See this https://prnt.sc/inkx7v (On your example, second box, I have 2 inside each box). My problem is when I have box very close, one value disappear, I need always show this value, on example that you do, now I have 2 values on each box, but I need only first value... Like last column, I need show (always) just 4501, 4001, 3500

Comment: But that doesn't happen with my example see: https://imgur.com/a/7v2Ke, as I wrote in the answer, I did some more changes than just paste the code you see in the answer. I will include it all in my answer so that there is no doubt.

Comment: I see. I don't have Firefox so that I can test with that here. So I suggest trying this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vdgphk3L/30/, if that does not work then I don't know how to fix it for firefox.

Comment: This problem doesn't concern browsers - in both Firefox and Chrome there're always 2 labels per point (you can check that in DOM tree). The only difference is that they're aligned differently - the bottom label looks like a shadow in Chrome and that's misleading.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case, it did look funny in Chome too. Thanks for pointing it out. @rafaelfndev here is a updated fiddle which will not draw 2 lables: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vdgphk3L/80/

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!